# Kindle for PC: Copy Limit, how strict and permanent is it?

Tags: kindle

When copying text in Kindle for PC, the app sent me a "You are getting close to the copy limit." message.

Am I right, that after I hit that limit, I can't copy any more text from that book, ever again?

Is that a way to lower the amount it says I've used?

Like just waiting long enough, or deleting Highlights, or something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about disabling legal / licensing limitations.

Comment: @MátéJuhász - How about now, that I've clarified? ... I just don't want to hit that limit, because I'm not sure what that'll do...